# How to remove duplicate data from array as per key value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need one help.I need to remove the duplicate set of data as per key value from array using php. I am explaining data below.

```
 Array
        (
            [id] => 494
            [1] => nurrr6lov
            [order_id] => nurrr6lov
            [2] => 126
            [pro_data_id] => 126
            [3] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [4] => 2.01
            [usp] => 2.01
            [5] => 0
            [discount] => 0
            [6] => 2.01
            [final_price] => 2.01
            [7] => 2.01
            [prod_tot_price] => 2.01
            [8] => ordered
            [delstatus] => ordered
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => nurrr6lov
            [pro_data_id] => 110
            [quantity] => 1
            [usp] => 13.33
            [discount] => 10
            [final_price] => 12.01
            [prod_tot_price] => 12.01
            [delstatus] => ordered
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 492
            [1] => td3baf6d7
            [order_id] => td3baf6d7
            [2] => 127
            [pro_data_id] => 127
            [3] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [4] => 2.23
            [usp] => 2.23
            [5] => 10
            [discount] => 10
            [6] => 2.01
            [final_price] => 2.01
            [7] => 2.01
            [prod_tot_price] => 2.01
            [8] => ordered
            [delstatus] => ordered
        )
)
```

From the above array i need if `order_id` is same it should remove any set of duplicate data.Here there are two set of `[order_id] => nurrr6lov` in this case i need to remove any set of data, Please help me.

Comment: which set of data? parent array element with entire data, of just this element(`[order_id] => nurrr6lov`)?

Comment: i need to remove exact that index of data.Suppose `nurrr6lov` arrises multiple times the it can remove 0th or 1st index of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that fact that an array in PHP doesn't allow duplicate keys, we can use that "feature" in such case. 
Solution using `array_walk` and `array_values` functions:

```
$filtered = [];

// $arr is your initial array
array_walk($arr, function($v) use (&$filtered){
    $filtered[$v['order_id']] = $v;
});

$filtered = array_values($filtered);
print_r($filtered); // will output an array of elements with unique 'order_id' values
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array by storing any id's you see, then checking if that id has been processed before.

```
$keys = [];    
$uniqueOrders = array_filter($array, function($o) use (&$keys) {
   if (isset($o['order_id']) && !in_array($o['order_id'], $keys)) {
      $keys[] = $o['order_id'];
      return true;
   }
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set order_id as array_key:

```
$withoutDublicates = array();
foreach ($arr as $data) {
    $withoutDublicates[$data['order_id']] = $data;
}
```

If you want first record:

```
$withoutDublicates = array();
foreach ($arr as $data) {
    if (empty($withoutDublicates[$data['order_id']])) {
        $withoutDublicates[$data['order_id']] = $data;
    }
}
```